# Running vb script does not "see" parameters unless I run with cscript prefix

Tags: vbscript, parameters

So I have a basic script that just prints out the parameters that are passed in:

```
projectName  = ""
if Wscript.Arguments.Count > 0 then
    projectName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
else
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "No project specified"
end if
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Running script on project: " & projectName
```

When I run the script from the command line:

`cit.vbs test`

I get the message "No project file specified"

If I run it like this:
`cscript vit.vbs test`

I get the output: "Running script on project test"

Why is that?, why can't I pass a parameter in without specifying cscript at the start?

**note** I have configured my windows to run vbs files using cscript not wscript because I find wscript has weird issues and I don't want GUI elements - but that's a different question

Comment: There is no print command in VBScript. Your code errors.

Comment: @Noodles sorry I forgot to add the print function..will add it

Comment: @Noodles no GUI in that I don't need to do things like MsgBox (which is a graphical element you can call with wscript).

Comment: @Noodles infact I just replaced the print function with part of what it does, because the other part is to log to a file

Comment: @Noodles also, I said GUI elements, not a GUI program, so no need to text-shout, thanks : )

Comment: You can call msgbox with cscript too. You misunderstand what a GUI program is. It is a program without a mandatory console window. Any program with or without windows that doesn't have a console window is a GUI program. GUI doesn't mean it has a graphical interface, it means it doesn't have a console interface. Programs with no interface (like wscript) are GUI programs.

Comment: @Noodles yes, this is valid, but as I mentioned I am not talking about a GUI program - just GUI elements :)   ... what I might mis-understand is the difference between cscript and wcsript. My (not the small example) script works with cscript but not wscript.

Comment: There's no difference. Console programs have a flag in the header that tell windows to automatically create a console. GUI programs do not. For a program to work as a console or GUI it must be structured in a certain way. However the program can structure itself as it wants. So when you want NO USER INTERFACE you use a GUI program, nothing graphical happens unless the program creates a window. Nothing stops a console program acting as a GUI program and creating windows and vice versa (GUI programs can create consoles if they wish). Both WScript and Cscript can be set to never show a dialog.

Comment: And as said before your problems are of your own making. You won't use the official way of changing the default script engine. It changes the default verb. At HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBSFile\Shell the default verb is listed - either Open for WScript or Open2 for CScript. At the verb themselves the command should be `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*` (or Cscript). Do things Microsoft's way and you won't have problems.

Comment: @Noodles "You won't use the official way", I would, if I knew it...so, what is the Microsoft way? to change the registry? The way I did it was through the Windows control panel, I would have thought that this is an official way? - but then, it is Microsoft, who change their mind every release... If you do mention the official way, feel free to stick it down as an answer, if its useful I will mark up (which is a more constructive use of our energies then arguing the point :)

Comment: When you type `wscript /?` it will tell you.

Comment: @Noodles, yes I did try this method too. But it had no effect and no difference from the way I had changed it. I still can't run `test.vbs 1 2 3` and pass parameters, I still have to do `cscript test.vbs 1 2 3` in order to pick up the parameters...

Comment: You don't read what I write. I told you how to fix what you did.

Comment: @Noodles I have been reading it all.  Are you talking about `"%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`? I get the same ... (with WScript). please explain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you call a script without naming the interpreter/host, depends on the assoc/ftype file association settings.

So use

```
assoc .vbs
.vbs=VBSFile
```

and

```
ftype VBSFile
VBSFile=%SystemRoot%\System32\CScript.exe "%1" %*
```

to make sure that the command line pattern contains the `%*` to forward the arguments.

**Update wrt comment:**

assoc/ftype are command line tools. A simple `assoc /?` resp. `ftype /?` will show you the details (including a sample that deals with parameters). But use the method you are familiar with.

Comment: Ah cool, I did not know you had to do that. Are you running those commands via the command line? - and if so , does that change it globally? (i made vbs association via the windows GUI interface)

Comment: You should be changing it via the correct tools. Type `wscript /?` (or `cscript /?`) to see how to change.

Comment: @Noodles - the problem is not to change the default host, but to handle/pass on the arguments.

Comment: He changed it manually, so incorrectly. Fix it by doing it correctly.

Comment: @Noodles I changed the association for .vbs via `Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations`. I changed it back now to windows based script instead of console based. But infact I still get the same issue. ftype VBSFile yields: `VBSFile="%SystemRoot%\System32\WScript.exe" "%1" %*`. So I am just calling my script with through cscript....

Comment: Note that no one else has this problem, it is specific to you. I told you how to set the default engine. Type `cscript /?` or `wscript /?`.

Comment: @Noodles just saw this comment. Well ... the fact that "no one else has this problem" is irrelevant. Am I not allowed to ask a question unless other people have the problem? ....lol, that is daft.

Comment: It's not a programming problem. It's you not doing things the way you should. This is a superuser question as it's about configuring file associations.

Comment: @Noodles If that is the case, I will move the question there. But I still don't see how I am not doing something the way I should, this is not confirmed, because I have tried all suggestions so far (both yours and Ekks)